# Convert hexadecimal file into unsigned int 32 Big-Endian in Java

Tags: java, integer, endianness

It might be a question already asked, but I have not found a satisfactory answer yet out there. In particular because this conversion has always been done in c or C++.

Btw, how do you convert an hexadecimal file (200MB) into its UINT32 Big-endian representation in Java?

This an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
54 00 00 00  -> 84       
55 F1 2E 04  -> 70185301
A2 3F 32 01  -> 20070306  
and so on
```

**EDIT**

```
File fileInputString = new File(inputFileField.getText());
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileInputString); 
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileDirectoryFolder.getText() +"/"+ fileInputString.getName());
byte[] fileContent = new byte[(int)fileInputString.length()];
fin.read(fileContent);
System.out.println("File Lenght" + fileContent.length);
for(int i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++){
Byte b = fileContent[i]; // Boxing conversion converts `byte` to `Byte`
int value = b.intValue();
out.write(value);
}
close();                                            
System.out.println("Done");
```

**EDIT 2**

```
File fileInputString = new File(inputFileField.getText());
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileInputString); 
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileDirectoryFolder.getText() +"/"+ fileInputString.getName());
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] fileContent = new byte[(int)fileInputString.length()];
System.out.println("File Lenght" + fileContent.length);
int bytesRead;
while (( bytesRead = fin.read(fileContent)) != -1) {
ByteBuffer.wrap(fileContent).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getLong();
bos.write(fileContent, 0, bytesRead);
}
out.write(bos.toByteArray()); 
System.out.println("Done");
```

**EDIT 3**

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output)); 
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(input))) {
int count = 0;        

while (count < input.length() - 4) {
    in.readFully(buffer, 4, 4);
    String s=Long.toString(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getLong());
    out.writeBytes( s + " ");
    count += 4;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Java doesn't have an unsigned integer type. How are you planning to store the data? You could use a long.

Comment: @TimB I do not know to be honest. In my example I used byte[] but it just replicate the original data without any modification

Comment: Is your example data skewed by one line? Shouldn't "54 00 00 00" be read as 84?

Comment: @jarnbjo Sorry, you are right. I do not know this happens, I just did copy and paste

Comment: I used [this](http://www.scadacore.com/field-applications/miscellaneous/online-hex-converter.html) website to convert the data and the info I expect to find is under UINT32 - Big Endian (ABCD)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code should hopefully suffice. It uses `long` values to ensure we can fully represent the range of positive values that four bytes can represent.

Note: this code assumes the hex input is four bytes. You may want to add some more checks and measures in production code.

```
private static long toLong(String hex) {
    hex = hex.replace(" ", "") + "00000000";
    byte[] data = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hex);
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getLong();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(toLong("54 00 00 00"));
    System.out.println(toLong("55 F1 2E 04"));
    System.out.println(toLong("A2 3F 32 01"));        
    System.out.println(toLong("FF FF FF FF"));
}
```

Output:

```
84
70185301
20070306
4294967295
```

---

Based on your recent edits, I propose some code such as the following. Note that it assumes your input is a multiple of four bytes in length. Any left-over bytes are ignored:

```
File input = new File("whatever");

byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>();

try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(input))) {
    int count = 0;        

    // Note: any trailing bytes are ignored
    while (count < input.length() - 4) {
        in.readFully(buffer, 4, 4);
        result.add(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer)
                .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getLong());
        count += 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to change your code to suits my needs but, I have faced many issues. As you can see in my question I need to import the data which is represented in hexadecimal but in practise it is binary code and convert it to a readable format (String perhaps). your function gets as input hexadecimal files not binary files. can you help me to figure out how to do it

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino Check edit above. This demonstrates how to consume an input stream in four byte chunks and perform the conversion.

Comment: My problem is not importing the data but writing it down in a new file

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino So how do you want your output file to look? Space-separated int values, like: `84 70185301 20070306`?

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino Can you not figure out how to achieve that from my answer? Rather than appending to the list, just output the string to a file followed by a space. I'm not really here to provide you exactly the code you want :-)

Comment: Can you give me a feedback of EDIT 3. However, there is something wrong. I get big number. I should get as first number for my file 1816469590 but I get 3264633735798063104

Comment: I understand your point, anyway thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch the byte order within the 4 bytes that form an int. The conversion is symetric, so when the input is little endian, output becomes big endian and vice versa.

```
Big Endian:    12 34 56 78
Little Endian: 78 56 34 12
```

So if you were doing that while processing an InputStream, read *four* bytes, and write them to output in reverse order.

Comment: In my specific case I am a bit confused between the raw file encoding and the raw file representation. when I import the data in a stream is binary data but when I visualise it in an editor it is in hexadecimal notation. I need to extract the data therefore I think I need not only to swap bits but only to convert them in String. What do you think about my statement?

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino The code you posted doesn't show anything related to string conversion, and what editor are you talking about? From your entire question I can't tell what kind of problem you're trying to solve.